# Stop items in listview from drawing beyond columns

Tags: wpf, listview

I am trying to make a listview in wpf that works like the Windows Explorer. I got everything (!), the tree, the navigating etc., I even got the rectangle drawing. The only thing I was not able to do is preventing the selected Items from drawing beyond the last column (see screenshot), my listview-mouseover and selected-items always draw the selecteditembackground beyond the last column.

I am thankful for every answer, this is driving me crazy.

I tried posting a pic of the problem, but I am new and i need 10 reputation (whatever this is) so I include a link to the screenshot. http://abload.de/img/listviewtwuu5.jpg

Edit:

There is some simple XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="MyListView">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Username}" Width="100"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

and here the code behind

```
Class MainWindow 
 Private Class User
     Public Property Username As String
 End Class

 Sub New()
     InitializeComponent()
     For i As Integer = 0 To 20
         MyListView.Items.Add(New User With {.Username = "User" & i.ToString})
     Next
 End Sub
End Class
```

Here a screenshot http://abload.de/img/listview21pb3o.jpg
As you can see in the first example (the original windows explorer) the selected item background does not draw beyond the last column, whereas in my example the selecteditem background goes way beyond and uses all available space within the listview control.

Comment: Might help if you posted some XAML or code that reproduces the problem you're describing - in fact, you're much more likely to get help if you do. Try making the smallest program that will compile and show the problem you're describing, and add it to your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Adding to what @Steve said, please see the [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page from the StackOverflow [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for help with that.

Comment: Just guessing ... What if you add one more, blank, empty column on the right side?

Comment: Indeed this is Standard WPF behavior. WPF sets the Background color of the whole row. The solution isn't that difficult. I haven't access to my development PC I'll post the trick in a moment.

Comment: Thanks, I hope you find the answer.
My idea was to overlay the empty column with a grid, but I don't want to do that

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I had the DataGrid in mind that offers more flexibility than the ListView in this special regard of styling. Right now I don't see a way. In case you can use a DataGrid instead: just use it, it does exactly what you need. No additional styling necessary.

Comment: Thanks, but I made an Explorer-like Control and everything works fine, except for the Items drawing beyond the last column.
A DataGrid is not an option. I try to find a workaround, but thanks anyway

Comment: Can't I override the ItemContainerStyle and bind the background of the selected Item to a gradientbrush with the first color bound to the combined Columnwidths and the second color transparent? If so, can anybody solve this?